# Custom keyboard in Android not handling back key correctly

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I've created a soft keyboard inside a v4 support Fragment but I think I'm going about it incorrectly. The keyboard shows up OK, but I can't hide it (the back button closes the programme). Otherwise it works fine. I would like the hardware Back button to be able to close just the keyboard.

```
myKeyboard = new Keyboard(getActivity(), R.xml.my_keyboard);
myKeyboardView = (MyKeyboardView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.my_keyboard_view);
myKeyboardView.setKeyboard(myKeyboard);
// this is a custom class to receive soft keyboard events
// just passes on the events to the Activity as normal
keyboardView.setOnKeyboardActionListener(new MyKeyboardListener(getActivity()));
```

To get the keyboard to show up, I use an `OnClickListener` on the target `EditText` with an animation and setting the `Visibility` to `VISIBLE`.

Should I be using this approach? I looked for a way to get the keyboard on the backstack but it's not obvious.